# FFmpeg-split.py can't determine video length

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

First, I'm not a developer. I'm trying to split a movie into 1 minute clips usinf [ffmpeg-split.py python script](https://github.com/c0decracker/video-splitter). I made sure FFmpeg is installed it trying a simple command and it worked like magic:

`ffmpeg -i soccer.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -codec copy -t 10 soccer1.mp4`

A new video file was created in the same folder.

I saved the FFmpeg-split.py in the same dir, updated python PATH and typed the following command:

`python ffmpeg-split.py -f soccer.mp4 -s 10`

what I got back was:

`can't determine video length`

I believe it just can't find the file. I switched video files and even deleted it and got the same message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running Windows? If so, ffmpeg-split.py won't work---it uses (rather lazily) a couple commands/features that don't exist on Windows

Answer (score 0):

first time I've seen that name!? Because I believe you were able to run ffmpeg from the command line and execute basic python stuff I recommend following my example as it should avoid any weird directory.connection.stuff in the given file (which i ignored). "Earlier that day": Let me ignore the .py script and share as follows:
    Assuming you ran
`ffmpeg -i soccer.mp4 ...stuff... soccer1.mp4`
from a windows.command.line...
    It would be better to write
`ffmpeg -t 10 -i "Z:\\full\\input\\path.mp4" -c copy "Z:\\full\\output\\path.mp4"`
    This says, run `ffmpeg`, `-t`=input.duration.seconds, `-i`=input.file.next,
        `"fullinpath"` in quotes cause spaces etc., `-c`=all.codecs, `copy`=atlantian.magic.trick,
        `"fulloutpath"` also to be safe, nothing else!

```
"Piping" through python to windows works great for this:

    import subprocess as subprocess
    def pegRunner(cmd): #Takes a list of strings we'll pass to windows.
        command = [x for x in cmd] # peg short for mpeg, shoulda used meg.gem.gepm.gipper.translyvania.otheroptions
        result = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        output, err = result.communicate()
        print result.wait()
        return "pegRannered"
    #########
    # Find the duration from properties or something. If you need to do this
    # often it's more complicated. Let's say you found 4mins33secs.
    ############
    leng = 4*60+33  # time in seconds
    last_dur = int(leng%60)  #remaining time after the 4 one.min.vids
    if last_dur == 0: num_vids = int(leng/60)
    else: num_vids = int(leng/60)+1
    for i in range(num_vids):
        da_command = ['ffmpeg']
        da_command.append('-ss')
        da_command.append(str(i*60))
        da_command.append('-t')
        if i != num_vids: da_command.append('60')
        else: da_command.append(str(last_dur))
        da_command.append('-i')
        da_command.append('Z:\\full\\input\\path.mp4') #this format!
        da_command.append('-c')
        da_command.append('copy')
        #optionally to overwrite!!!!            da_command.append('-y')
        da_command.append('Z:\\full\\output\\path\\filename_'+str(i)+'.mp4')
        print pegRunner(da_command)
    print "Finished "+str(i)+" filez."
```

This should handle the 1.min pieces and provide a good starting place for ffmpeg from python.